# Permission Denied on move_uploaded_file to another server in IIS

Tags: php, iis, copy, file-permissions

I have a PHP web application running on IIS, which allows a user to upload a file from a simple html form. The uploaded file is then moved to a folder on another server. This is working correctly on Apache, but fails on IIS with the error:

> function['move_uploaded_file']failed to open stream: Permission denied
>   in...

I've checked all the permissions on the directories. If I run a simple PHP script through the command line to copy a file from the server into the folder on the other server it works correctly, so I suspect the problem is with IIS.

```
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES ["file"] ["tmp_name"], "\\\\000.00.0.00\\tia\\web\\upload\\" .$_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
```

Comment: You need to show the PHP code you're using to handle the file, and an example of an exact error message.

Comment: @user can you edit it into the question and format it as code using the `{}` button?  That's easier to read, thanks. Can you show the full code in the receiving script? Also, can you confirm that you are using a `\\` network path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see in your comment, you are using a `\\` prefixed network share as the target for your `move_uploaded_file()` operation.

I'll bet a beer that PHP isn't allowed to access that share. Remember, PHP runs with IIS's permissions!

Try saving to a local, globally writable path first. If that works, you know you have to fix the share's permissions.

Comment: No beer for you (yet)! PHP is able to write to that share without problems - if I execute the script through the command line directly on the server. eg: c:\php\php.exe c:\copy.php. Where copy.php contains the same commands that fail when I run through the process in a browser.

Comment: @user but if you run PHP that way, it runs as *you* with your account permissions. If you run it in the browser, it runs as the IIS user. Try a local path, that should show pretty quickly whether I win my beer :)

Comment: The folder I am trying to copy to has full control from any request originating from the web server - regardless of the user. :(

Comment: I get the same message: Warning: move_uploaded_file(...) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in

Comment: @user `$_FILES ["file"] ["tmp_name"]` definitely exists and is accessible?

Comment: Pekka you're falling into same pit. Instead of reading you are guessing. I can't believe it's you.

Answer (score 2):

This has been covered already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511793/php-file-copy-to-another-server-access-filesystem-on-other-server). Quoting the reason here:

> You have mapped target directory to a share such as \server2\files. These mappings are only available to the current users (eg, the admin account), not to the IUSR account that your php is probably running as (assuming IIS). Solution, don't use mappings, instead use the full 'unc' path name, ie '\server\share\folder\file.ext', also remember that the IUSR account will need access to these shares/folders/files

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer, however I am using the full UNC path, not a mapped directory, so this was not the solution to the problem. :/

Comment: OK. But, how do you confirm that IUSR has access to `\\000.00.0.00\tia\web\upload\` ?

Comment: Instead of specifying write access per user, we have specified that any request that originates from the server has full control.